# Catalog Price Rule containing several SKU-s doesn't work

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, catalog-price-rules, bug

Upgraded a store from CE 1.5 to 1.9.0.1 and while everything else works just fine several Catalog Price Rules stopped working. After some investigation I found something weird:

```
ANY condition is TRUE
  SKU "is one of" sku1
  SKU "is one of" sku2
```

works just fine.

```
ANY condition is TRUE
  SKU "is one of" sku1,sku2
```

doesn't work.

Any ideas what causes this anomaly, how to fix it and why is this behavior different from older versions?

**UPDATE:** Preliminary investigation reveals that it's actually a bug in Magento core ... once I have a fix, I'll post it here as an answer.

Comment: What about `contains` instead of `is one of` ? I recalled having problems with the later early on 1.8.

Comment: I'll test it out tomorrow. However even if it works, there's still a considerable risk that longer SKU codes may contain shorter ones and thus cause unwanted false positive discounts.

Comment: I think contains is about elements, so each SKU would count in their entirety, not as prefixes.

Comment: 'ANY condition is TRUE' and SKU 'is one of' should work as you mentioned. Double check the SKU field on the individual products sometimes there is a space at the end and for some reason Magento doesn't trim those off automatically.

Comment: It doesn't work. Try it out yourself. At first glance it looks like magento is unable to explode comma separated values.

Comment: This issue has been solved in Magento EE 1.14.2.0. Please see my answer for a fix for other versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, but on 1.8.1.0, so i tried to update to 1.9.0.1, still the same issue.

But I found why this happens:

This method: Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract::prepareConditionSql()

Returns a part of a sql-statement, like so: `cpf`.`sku` IN('SKU')

What's interesting is that the IN contains the exact string that was entered in admin, like so: `cpf`.`sku` IN('SKU1, SKU2, SKU3')

Note the lack of ' between the SKU's, the string isn't exploded, so it won't find any sku's like that sting.

To fix the issue i modified (copied to local first of course) that method to look like this;

```
 public function prepareConditionSql()
{
    $alias     = 'cpf';
    $attribute = $this->getAttribute();
    $value     = $this->getValue();
    $operator  = $this->correctOperator($this->getOperator(), $this->getInputType());
      if ($attribute == 'category_ids') {
        $alias     = 'ccp';
        $attribute = 'category_id';
        $value     = $this->bindArrayOfIds($value);
    }

    // Andre Klang: This fixes issue with "is one of" & "is not one of"
    if(!is_array($value) && in_array($operator,array('()','!()'))) {
        $tmp = explode(',',$value);
        foreach($tmp as $trim) $values[] = trim($trim); 
        $value = $values;
    }

    /** @var $ruleResource Mage_Rule_Model_Resource_Rule_Condition_SqlBuilder */
    $ruleResource = $this->getRuleResourceHelper();

    return $ruleResource->getOperatorCondition($alias . '.' . $attribute, $operator, $value);
}
```

I also reported this as a bug to Magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/278

Comment: I actually built a fix very similar. Haven't had time to post it here, so thanks and a well deserved up vote.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that this issue has been solved in Magento EE 1.14.2.0.
The fix is darn simple :

In `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract::prepareConditionSql()` :

replace

`$value = $this->getValue();` by `$value = $this->getValueParsed();`

Comment: So just wait for CE 1.9.2.0 to be released to have this fix for CE ;) http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/65178/3326

Answer (score 0):

Issue with catalog price rules still exist on latest Magento CE 1.9.1 and EE 1.14.1.0  , problems even more complex, details and hot fix for described problem and few more  http://firebearstudio.com/blog/catalog-price-rules-core-bug-in-magento-ce-1-9-1-and-ee-1-14-1-0-array-to-string-conversion-error-and-incorrect-price-rules-behavior.html , all reported to bug tracker but no any reaction yet. Core patch with fix on GitHub - https://github.com/biotech/Magento1.9-CatalogPriceRulesFix

Comment: Please elaborate a link is not an answer.