# When is Magento CE 1.9.2 going to be released?

Tags: security, patches, ce-1.9.2.0, ee-1.14.2.0, ce-1.9.1.1

What is the release date for Magento Community Edition 1.9.2?

In Magento's [official post](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/introducing-enterprise-edition-1142) they say it will be released in "the next few weeks", which is kind of vague. Does anyone know a (unofficial) release date?

Magento EE 1.14.2 is already available and I've seen that all the [latest security patches](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63936/3326) are already in there. We've updated all our current running EE 1.14.1 development projects to 1.14.2 already and also want to do so for our 1.9.1 CE projects as soon as possible.

**UPDATE:**
CE 1.9.1.1 was released on May 1st and contains the latest patches. Still my question remains

Comment: may be @benmarks can help.

Comment: They have already released 1.9.1.1 with all updated security patches on 1st of May. It covers the latest code exploit patches. You can go with it for now. https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/. Regarding release of 1.9.2 i am not sure when they are going to release. I haven't came across the mention of it too. It would be nice if you can share a link

Comment: It's out along with a new patch SUPEE-6285 as of today 20150707. The patch is included in 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Magento CE 1.9.2 has been released

***Update:*** Today 7th of July, 2015 Magento CE 1.9.2 has been released: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Magento Community Edition 1.9.2 includes SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, and the also today released SUPEE-6285 patch.

---

***History:***

---

**FIRST ANSWER** (May 8):

I have contacted Magento through the Partner Portal support panel (thanks for the hint!) and I have received an answer. It is clear, but not exact and not satisfying ;)

Here's some quotations from in between the formal and slick support style answer.

**Magento's response:**

> "there's no definite date yet for the release of Magento Community 1.9.2"

And:

> "[*The*] response from the Product Manager regarding the possible release date":
>
> "they are still discussing options for the date but June is the soonest possible release month since there are still some security fixes and performance improvements they need to implement. It is still not definite and it might still change"

So in short:

> "it [*the release*] is still being a few months off"

**UPDATE** (May 19):

> "The Product Manager [*said that the*] target for the release date is **end of May or early June**. They had to push the security updates [*SUPEE-5994 patch*] first as this was more critical."

**UPDATE** (June 8):

> "[*...*] due to the recent security issue, the tentative expected date was moved to July around the 9th"

### Security fixes

In my own activity here on Magento SE and in my search for an answer, I stumbled upon this question "[Shoplift vulnerability if admin panel is hidden?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/65707/3326) " which's answers refer to a MageHero blog post about [renaming the Magento admin URL](http://magehero.com/posts/886/renaming-the-magento-backend-for-extra-security-or-not). In the comments on the post, different persons are referring to the fact that the admin URL, although changed, can still be discovered in multiple ways. Ben Marks responds [on May 4th](http://magehero.com/posts/886/renaming-the-magento-backend-for-extra-security-or-not#comment-2003089731) "This issue is currently being patched."

Probably this is one thing they want to have fixed before releasing anything and that it is one of the issues that has pushed the release from ["in the next few weeks"](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/introducing-enterprise-edition-1142) to "a few months"

**UPDATE** (May 15): The patch [SUPEE-5994 was released](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html). These are a bunch of security fixes that will be already included in Magento CE 1.9.2.

**UPDATE** (July 7): Magento CE 1.9.2 has finally been released and along side of it a security patch [SUPEE-6285 was released](http://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Critical-new-Magento-security-patch/m-p/10137). This patch is already included in Magento CE 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. And as i expected a generic response where they are not sure. As a side note, i have been keeping my eye on this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66946/how-did-they-find-my-custom-admin-url specifically around third party or custom modules that have a custom admin route. If the modules are known then the admin route can be discovered.

Comment: God knows what kind of a release process you have when some security fixes that you've already released as patches have to push the release date of the next version back a month...

Comment: 7th of July (instead of June)

Answer (score 3):

Its impossible to give an exact date. Usually it can take anywhere from 2 weeks to months. EE is top priority for updates so they usually come first. CE on the other hand, we will not know for sure.

I can say this though. If you are working with EE clients, then you should have access to open a support ticket via the partner portal. Ask them the question there and you should get a response and definite answer from your region rep or someone in the core team.

Comment: I know that EE always comes first, this is part of the paid service of EE customers. For CE, I'm sure they would have an internal planning for the release right? As a major development company they would have to have some planning on resources and whatever is going to be done around a release. So I'm sure internally they know exactly when the release will happen and this is not a window of "2 weeks to months".

Comment: Ye, all im saying is that with CE they have never given a specific date on when the next CE release will be. Im sure they have an internal process for planning and what not, but thats all depended on what ever factors are within the plan which we do not know about. Hence why i said, if u need to know right now when the expected release date is for CE, open a ticket from the partner portal and ask them directly, as you more likely to get an answer from them straight away, rather than using conventional methods.

Comment: Else i can easily ask them for you if you dont have access in partner portal

Comment: Well I just did. Thanks for the hint! It is a EE support portal though. You can only select EE versions from the dropdown. Just selected 1.14.2 ;)

Comment: Ye, they will help regardless. Let us know the outcome, im interested to know :)

Comment: Your hint to contact Magento through the Partner Portal guided me to an answer, so I think it would be fair to award you the bounty...

Answer (score 3):

The usual answer in Software Developing and also a lot of other fields:
"***When its Done***"

There is a lot of quality assurance connected with a release, to avoid another patch release during the next days.
The problem is, if there is a blocking issue detected, it goes back to developing, and then the QA needs at least partially get repeated, which can depending on other important tasks move a release more then a week.

With an RC release, or even a 1.y.0 release there is some free space for bugs, but with every bugfix release, the acceptance of new bugs lowers, making the QA more important and the release date less predictable.

There may be a Roadmap, but its not an official one. And directly install a patch on the first day it got releases is sometimes tricky, why a lot of developers tend to wait a week and hear if others have problems with special edge cases.

If you are searching for an official answer, you should contact Magento or one of the Community Managers directly.