# Security Patch Installed But Still Getting Critical Message In Backend

Tags: patches

I have successfully installed the latest Magento security patches. I did this via SSH. And used this official Magento documentation as a guide:

https://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

After running the sh command I got a success message:

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... Patch was
>   applied/reverted successfully.

I then did the usual Clear Cache and Run Compilation Process in my Magento backend.

However when I logout of my backend and log back in, I am still greeted with the Critical messages saying:

> Urgent: Immediately install Magento critical security patches

Does this mean the patches were not installed successfully? How can I tell is a security patch is in place correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go `admin>System>notification` `Urgent: Immediately install Magento critical security patches`  make `Make   as read`.There  have no process to disable the message after install ssh file.So you need to disable message manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just what I was looking for. As a bonus, could you tell me whether there is anyway to check if the security patch has been added successfully? As mentioned I got a success message in SSH, but how am I to know that it is running okay? Thanks again.

Comment: please check the link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patches, and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65707/shoplift-vulnerability-if-admin-panel-is-hidden

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind those notifications. Just be sure you have installed the patches.

Also you can check the store in https://shoplift.byte.nl/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using this tool are you not just telling this site what your admin backend url is? Is it not just a matter of time before someone hacks this sites database and has every site who's used it's admin backend url details? I know people can hack your admin regardless, but this would make it easier.