# Magento 2.1.1 Catalog Price Rule using SKU's

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.2

I tried to add a CATALOG price rule, not a cart price rule, using multiple sku's.  I'm on Magento 2.1.2.  In the past I have been able to create price rules (i.e. 30% off) and added products using SKU's.  The products then show up on the front end with the discounted price.

I recently just tried this and found that only 2 of the many sku's I have added are being affected.  I tried several times to add the sku's and no matter what, only 2 of the sku's work.

I then checked the database table and the RULES are there all written to the DB correctly, but under the rules, it seems that the SKU's I add in the admin will not be written to the DB table that lists the item #'s under each rule?

Does anyone have any issues with this?  There are a number of the posts about this, but nothing with a definite answer.  I have even found a bug report, but that was for CE 1.8. and 1.9 [HERE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/catalog-price-rule-containing-several-sku-s-doesnt-work).  I also found an issue on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8215) where a contributor states that "in magento you have no ability to create Catalog rule based on list of SKU. You can create rule only based Attribute Set or Category." which doesn't seem to be correct.

Does anyone out here have any concrete solution or idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to edit the SKU attribute to make it selectable for Promo Rule Conditions in Magento 2.1.4.