# Catalog Price Rules "SKU is not one of"

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

Magento Version 1.9.3.7

The scenario is:

I need to set up a Catalog Price Rule for specific brand's products.
So i set up condition "**Manufacturer  is  BrandName**".

Now I need to exclude some product from thet rule.

If i set up "SKU  is not one of" with just one sku it works fine, but if is an array of skus the rule will be applied to all catalog.

The follow is applied to all catalog:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Manufacturer  is  BrandName
    SKU  is not one of  sku1, sku2
```

the follow works as expected:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Manufacturer  is  BrandName
    SKU  is not one of  sku1
```

the follow works as expected:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Manufacturer  is  BrandName
    SKU  is one of  sku1, sku2
```

Guess the array will break the condition set so that it will result "empty condition" than good for all products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is in **Mage_Rule_Model_Resource_Rule_Condition_SqlBuilder** class in

```
public function getOperatorCondition()
```

need to change on line 109

```
$result = implode(in_array($operator, array('()', '!()')) ? ' OR ' : ' AND ', $results);
```

with

```
$result = implode(in_array($operator, array('()', '[]')) ? ' OR ' : ' AND ', $results);
```

than everythig works as expected

Comment: `[]` is just another array syntax and no replacement for `!()`. I'm pretty sure this will break other rules. Not exactly the same, but may helperfl for others ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/catalog-price-rule-containing-several-sku-s-doesnt-work

Comment: @sv3n `'[]'  => Mage::helper('rule')->__('contains')` as you can see in Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Abstract. What I've done is to have the "OR" condition when operatator is "FIND_IN_SET" and the "AND"  condition when is "NOT FIND_IN_SET"

Comment: @sv3n as is said in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71332/15051 that issue is been solved in CE 1.9.3 what i've posted is different